# Map not loading from text file

Tags: tilemap

Ok, so I have a text file filled with 0s and 1s. When there are 1s, I want the code to add a block to the block array. For some reason it is not reading it right at all.

World.java:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;

class World {
    Image ground;
    Block[] blocks;
    int mapWidth = 40;
    int mapHeight = 22;

    void setWorld(String map) {
        try { 
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(map));
            String line;
            int enc = -1;
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String values[] = line.split(" ");
                for (String str : values) {
                    int str_int = Integer.parseInt(str);
                    if (str_int == 1) {
                        enc++;
                        System.out.println("x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
                        //blocks[enc] = new Block(x * 32, y * 32, 32, 32, 1);
                    }
                    y++;
                }
                x++;               
            }

        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe swap where you increment x and y?

Comment: Debugging requires figuring out how & why actual results aren't matching expected results. You gave the code, but without knowing the input, the expected output & the actual output, we don't have much to go on. What's the simplest, smallest test case that fails? What did you expect instead?

Comment: Your telling us "it does not read right", but your not telling us how it *is* reading. Your describing a problem by telling us that it *exists*, but your not telling us *what it is*.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it.

I swapped the `x` and the `y` increments, and set `x` to `0` when I incremented `y`. I also use a list to store the blocks, instead of an array.

Comment: Make sure you come back to accept the answer, so others know this is solved